# What's the jQuery equivalent to this, and what does it do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm converting some javascript to jQuery from ExtJS and I don't know what this does so I'm not sure what it converts to...

```
hideTimeout = setTimeout(this.hideAll.createDelegate(this), delay);
```

delay = 200

What I'm not sure about is the `createDelegate(this)`...

**update**

All the JS is...

```
    Menu.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var that = this;

            this.ui.link.bind("mouseover", function (e) {
                that.show();
            });
            this.ui.link.bind("mouseout", function (e) {
                that.hide();
            });

            var subOptions = $("li", this.ui.parent);

            $.each(subOptions, function (el) {
                el = $(el);

                el.bind("mouseover", that.cancelTimeout, this);
                el.bind("mouseout", that.hide, this);
            });
        },
        hideAll: function () {
            $("#hd .nav ul ul").hide();
        },
        show: function () {

            this.hideAll();

            this.cancelTimeout();

            showTimeout = setTimeout((function () {
                this.el.show();
            }).createDelegate(this), delay);
        },
        hide: function () {
            this.cancelTimeout();

            hideTimeout = setTimeout(this.hideAll.createDelegate(this), delay);
        },
        cancelTimeout: function () {
            clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
            clearTimeout(showTimeout);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're in a `setTimeout`, `this` will represent the `window` object.

<s>I don't know ExtJS, but it appears to be creating a delegate handler on the `window`.</s>

Probably best to reference the ExtJS docs. According to the [docs for `createDelegate`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Function):

> Creates a delegate (callback) that sets the scope to obj. Call directly on any function. Example: this.myFunction.cre...

---

EDIT: I believe it would be called like this:

```
hideTimeout = setTimeout($.proxy( this.hideAll, this), delay);
```

It will ensure that when `hideAll` is called, it will be called in its current context.

You can do the same thing for the anonymous function passed to `setTimeout` in `show`:

```
showTimeout = setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
                 this.el.show();
              }, this), delay);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give you enough details to really get a picture of what was going on.... and what do you mean delegate handler?  How do I do that in jQuery?

Comment: So how do I do that with jQuery?

Comment: @Webnet - It appears to set a context for the Function it is called against. So the function it would affect here would be `hideAll`. jQuery has a method called `jQuery.proxy()` that is similar, but it may not be needed. Depends on how the `hideAll` is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the same thing with jQuery like so:

```
hideTimeout = setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(this, "hideAll"), delay);
```

**EDIT:** Since the method `hideAll` doesn't contain a reference to `this`, you can accomplish this even more simply:

```
hideTimeout = setTimeout(this.hideAll, delay);
```